# LightSwitch HTML Client project fails to load

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, client, visual-studio-lightswitch

I just run into a problem I already solved, once again. So, I want to put it here just in case anybody else has to face the same issue. I will ask the question as usual and then answer it myself.

After an update (November Update, Update 4) of Office Tools for Visual Studio 2013 an error occurs (“project ‘projectname’ can not be loaded because one or more projects it references failed to load ”) as soon as I try to open a LightSwitch solution that includes an html client project (the error does not occur when opening a solution without an html client project). When trying to reload the project (by right-click on the project in the solution and then clicking “reload”) an error message pops up “one or more errors occurred”. Since the solution can’t be built without the not loaded project, my project seems to be lost – at least the html client part of it. All I can do is to delete the html client project and restart it from scratch – but that’s neither a solution nor an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to reopen the solution multiple times as well as trying to reload the project multiple times one message popped up, telling me exactly what I needed to know (I don’t remember the message exactly, but you might be able to get the idea): “office tools for visual studio seem to be installed in a different language than expected. Use this link to download them in correct language: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=392577&clcid=0x407 “.

Turns out I had installed Visual Studio in German and the office tool’s November Update was in English. I downloaded the correct version by following the provided link, installed it and all my problems were gone. Finally, I’m able to work on my project again : )

But once again I ran into this weird problem. This time I installed Visual Studio in English (just to avoid the weird update issue with the wrong language that I ran into previously) and I installed Office Tools for Visual Studio 2013 in English. When trying to open my LightSwitch solution (created using the German Visual Studio I had before) the same problem occurred again …

I already knew that this problem is caused by some language-stuff that fails to match or something similar (please, excuse me for being inaccurate, but that’s all I found out so far), so I decided to install the German language pack for Visual Studio 2013, repair the installation of Office Tools for Visual Studio 2013 using the German version and change the language of Visual Studio 2013 back to German once again – I restart Visual Studio 2013, open my solution and everything is working just fine.